# Could not get trait set for device iPad14,3 with version 16.1

Tags: ios, xcode, ios16

Ever since I started using Xcode 14.1, I've been seeing this warning with my asset files

> Could not get trait set for device iPad14,3 with version 16.1

I've checked the build log file and It doesn't have any more details than that message. It happens when trying to compile the asset file.

Please let me know if you know to which trait set is it referring.

Comment: Are you using 14.1 beta 3?

Comment: I'm using Xcode Version 14.1 (14B47b), its the RC2 I believe.

Comment: The same happening for me, but for watchOS, `Could not get trait set for device Watch6,9 with version 9.1`

Comment: I'm still getting the same iPad warning with the production release of Xcode 14.1.

Comment: Similar warning on Xcode 14.2: `Could not get trait set for device iPad14,5 with version 16.2`

Comment: Still getting similar warnings on Xcode 15.0.1: "... xcassets: Could not get trait set for device iPad14,3 with version 17.0.1"

Comment: also seeing this on Xcode 15.2

Answer (score 4):

The bug is still present in the latest Xcode (14.3) with projects that were created on older Xcode versions.

To fix it, simply create a new asset catalog. Interestingly, an empty one will do, but I just moved my app icons to it and deleted the old one made with the previous Xcode version.

Of course (because it would have been too simple), there is an additional bug with Xcode 14.3 - if you try to create a full icon set and set your target to iOS 11, upon submission to the app store you will get a warning about having a single-side app icon in the bundle with an iOS version less than 12.

Edit: Updating to 14.3.1 will not fix the bug either. It might actually bring back the warning, so you'd have to again create a new asset catalog.

Comment: I have tried this and the traits warning message disappeared on creating a new assets catalog and indeed stayed away after importing in all the assets from the old catalog to the new catalog, but re-appeared again when I deleted the now redundant and empty catalog! Did you delete the old catalog in a particular way?

Comment: @ChrisLindsey I did delete it and was fine for a couple of days. Then I updated my Xcode and the message appeared again, so at this point I just made a new empty one to stop the message (I even called it "Empty") and I am giving up trying to figure out another of Apple's bugs :D